# Get all related objects without knowing model name in Django

Tags: python, django

I have abstract model:

```
class CModel(CParent):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And have two models based on this abstract model:

```
class Model1(CModel):
    pass

class Model1_A(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name="a")

class Model1_A_B(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model1_A, related_name="b")
```

and second:

```
class Model2(CModel):
    def all_obj(self):
        ...
        list = Model2_A_B.objects.filter(model__model__pk=self.pk).all()
        ...

class Model2_A(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model2, related_name="a")

class Model2_A_B(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model2_A, related_name="b")
```

And now I would like to move function all_obj() to abstact class, so it will be avalible in Model1 too, but for Model1 i need something like this:

```
list = Model1_A_B.objects.filter(model__model__pk=self.pk).all()
```

How can i make all_obj() work for any model name?

I came up with something like this:

```
list = eval(self.a.all()[:1][0].b.all()[:1][0].__class__.__name__).objects.filter(model__model__pk=self.pk)
```

But i don't think that this is right way to do. And there is problem with that, it is work only if self.a.all()[:1][0] have related objects but this is not always true.

Comment: Why not just write a generic function instead of a class method if you want it to be accessible to all the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CModel(models.Model):
    _related_model = None

   def all_obj(self):
       if self._related_model is None:
           # you could also return None or an EmptyQueryset or whatever
           raise NotImplementedError("CModel subclasses must define '_related_model'")

       # you don't need the `.all()` after a `.filter()`
       return self._related_model.objects.filter(model__model__pk=self.pk)

   # your code here

class Model1(CModel):
    # note that you'll have to define Model_1_A_B before 
    _related_model = Model_1_A_B

    # etc

class Model2(CModel):
    # note that you'll have to define Model_2_A_B before 
    _related_model = Model_2_A_B

    # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from this code all your models are the same but with different naming.

Why not create base class for Modeling and create instance to each model?

Regarding the all_obj(self) just make it generic(global)

Comment: It is just part of code, this models not exactly the same. Problem is: i need to get all related objects of all related objects for any model name.

Comment: In that case i suggest using the function as generic.